# Why is a rectangular wing with winglets not better than an elliptical wing?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing, drag, winglets

Why is a simple rectangular wing with winglets not better than an elliptical wing in terms of induced drag and produced lift?

Comment: It’s an interesting information. I am curious to read the reference behind the description.

Answer (score 1):

If using Prandtl's lifting line theory, then mathematically/analytically, ignoring issues of wing weight that lead to bell shaped lift distributions and other sorts of intrusions of reality (e.g., stall behavior) the elliptical wing with the elliptical lift distribution is *optimal* for minimizing induced drag given a fixed wing area.

You can get an elliptical distribution of lift from a rectangular wing via twist, winglets, or other mechanisms, but it will only be elliptical at one cL value. At other values, it will not be elliptical, and thus suboptimal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "optimal" and "can't be improved on" because a planar elliptical wing does not produce an elliptical lift distribution.

Comment: A wing with an elliptical chord distribution (and minimal sweep, minimal dihedral, and moderate aspect ratio) produces an elliptical lift distribution.

Comment: No, a planar elliptical planform wing definitely does not produce an elliptical lift distribution. (Twisted wings are a different matter.) This was known to Prandtl and his students as far back as 1937.
See, for example, among many dozens of other papers:

Peter F. Jordan, "Exact Solutions for Lifting Surfaces", AIAA Journal, Vol. 11, No. 8, 1973., pp. 1123-1129.

Peter F. Jordan, "On Lifting Wings with Parabolic Tips", ZAMM 54, pp. 463-477, 1974.

Comment: OK, I'll caveat my answer to what Prandtl's LLT infers.

Comment: @MikeY Re your answer, why would I want an elliptical distribution to begin with? Isn't this only the optimal solution for a finite wing, i.e. one where at the ends of the wing pressure from below the wing can freely travel to the upper side?
Couldn't winglets - if large enough and going in both directions - create a "barrier", effectively turning a finite wing into an infinite one?

Comment: @Lysistrata So what planform  of a wing without twist, sweep, dihedral, winglets ... produces an elliptical lift distribution? Can you post an image that contrasts it with an elliptical wing?

Comment: I assume neither of you can answer my questions?

Comment: @xnor, assume for a second that by putting a surface into the tip vortex you can improve performance. You should be able to put the surface anywhere in the vortex and see the improvement, as the vortex is symmetrical about its rotation. Up, down, or *horizontal outwards*. This means you can arbitrarily pick a point on a wing, and *consider what is outboard of it to be winglet*. So the question is, is there anything to be gained by bending the wing up?

Comment: There are some examples in D.W.F. Standingford's PhD thesis:
https://digital.library.adelaide.edu.au/dspace/handle/2440/19063
(Disclaimer: I assisted with several sections.)

Unfortunately, techniques like vortex lattice methods or Tuck's method aren't sufficiently accurate to produce "exact" elliptical distributions. I'm not sure if anyone has improved on that situation recently.

Comment: @xnor: People will answer when they have time. Don't start assuming your question is so important that we have to answer it within a day or two.